# Compass transition opacity on background-image alone

Tags: css, css-transitions, compass-sass, transition

I want to make a background image 50% opaque on hover, and leave all other elements on the page as they were. Here's my SASS:

```
.background {
  div {
    @include background(image-url("background.jpg"));
    padding-bottom: 68.53%;
    @include transition-property(opacity);
    @include transition-duration(2s);
    @include transition-timing-function(ease-in);
    &:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
  }

  #cover {
    @include background-size(cover);
  }
}

.intro {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  left: 20%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  max-width: 650px;
}

h2.intro {
  font-size: 3.5em;
}
```

And here's the html:

```
<div class="intro">
  <h2 class="intro">Introduction</h2>
</div>
<div id="anchor">
  <div class="background">
    <div id="cover">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently the transition itself works beautifully, but it also makes "Introduction" opaque, when I want opacity applied to the background image alone. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This ended up solving it. The SASS:

```
#intro {
  div {
    @include background(image-url("nathanstudio.jpg"));
    padding-bottom: 68.53%;
  }

  #cover {
    @include background-size(cover);
  }

  @include transition-property(opacity);
  @include transition-duration(2s);
  @include transition-timing-function(ease-in);
  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

h2#intro {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 10%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000000;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="intro">
    <div id="cover">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<h2 id="intro">Composer<br>Sound Designer</h2>
```

So it's a matter of keeping the stuff that you don't want to transition outside of the div's of the stuff that you do, and then positioning things so they go where you want. Seems simple now ;)